# Android M, not ask every start for storage permission

Tags: android, permissions, storage, android-6.0-marshmallow

My app needs to access the user's storage in near to every activity. How can I access the storage without making the app ask at every app startup for the permission to access it with the new Android M permission model? (Read and write)

Thanks!

Comment: You only need to ask if you do not already hold the permission. What is your specific concern?

Comment: That the user is prompted on every app startup to give memory access to be able to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to prompt the user "on every app startup to give memory access to be able to do anything", then don't do that. Only call `requestPermissions()` if `checkSelfPermission()` returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    init();
  }
  else {
    requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
      REQUEST_STORAGE);
  }
}
```

(native API Level 23 methods shown; you may want to use `ContextCompat and`ActivityCompat` for backwards compatibility)

Or, only call `requestPermissions()` if the user does something positive in the UI that needs `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (e.g., clicks an action bar item) and you do not already have the permission.